# Who has authority to add a new node in Quorum

Tags: private-blockchain, quorum

According to [this](https://medium.com/@didil/enterprise-ethereum-private-transactions-with-quorum-b0574bb60700) tutorial of `Quorum` a `regulator` is able to view the result of voting.

1) What else responsibilities does regulator have?

2) How is the regulator selected from the participants of the blockchain network?

3) How are new participants and nodes added to the private permissioned network?

4) Does the regulator have the right to add participants to the private permissioned blockchain network? If yes, isn't it a politically centralized system? To read more about political decentralization read [this](https://medium.com/@VitalikButerin/the-meaning-of-decentralization-a0c92b76a274) post by Vitalik.

5) Are all private permissioned network are infrastructurally decentralized, politically centralized and logically centralized systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a little pre-amble: in Quorum all participants are known and pre-defined -- that is, every node that participates in a given blockchain cluster and this is done at the genesis / spin up time. At the same time keys are shared and assigned -- the keys are per node. So once we set something like this up we can that either arbitrarily say node X is your regulator or in a real one the key will be shared by async means (through email for example).

So now to some explanations. A regulator would generally be a node that sees all private comms between some parties for the cases when it needs to mediate between disagreeing parties. As a regulator, they are generally silent monitor, but in some cases they could also act on the network.

A good example of this is 5NodeRTGS example and you can check it out here: https://github.com/bacen/quorum-examples/tree/master/examples/5nodesRTGS

Comment: Thanks for your response. I went through the example that you have shared and it helped me to understand the concept. I still don't understand the purpose of the regulator as it is somewhat (politically)  centralized entity in a decentralized system.

Comment: I agree, and those are only needed if youre network may require oversight or mediation via a third party. The entire reason to have it in Quorum is that some of the txns are private and thus only visible between the parties in them, so a 3rd party may be required that sees all.