# how can I store a data in quorum smart contract that no one can see it

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, quorum

I want to store a number in smart contract that blockchain nodes should guess that number and send it to smart contract and then smart contract should compare it with data stored in it, and if they are the same give a reward to that node.. so smart contract should be hidden and nodes should not see that number... is there any way to do that? can quorum do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using quorum. Refer the following blog for more details -

https://medium.com/@didil/enterprise-ethereum-private-transactions-with-quorum-b0574bb60700

Let me know if any further clarification is required.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you so much Soham. I have a question; in this case because of the regulator existence we can not claim that it's a decentralized network, and also we can not eliminate trust to third party. am i right or not?

Comment: Welcome, glad to help you. You are right, have a look at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/57987/who-has-authority-to-add-a-new-node-in-quorum